# How to use Nativescript worker with typescript?

Tags: typescript, worker, angular2-nativescript

I'm trying to use Nativescript Worker with Typescript but i had this error:

> ERROR Error: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to find module: "../shared/workers/workername.js", relative to: app//

This is my code, i'm using the same template as in Nativescript documentation:

```
var worker = new Worker("../shared/workers/workername");
    worker.onmessage = (msg) => {
        if(msg.data.success) {

            console.log("resultat: " + msg.data.result);
            worker.terminate();
        }
        else {
            console.log("error during process !!!!!");
        }
    };

    worker.onerror = (err) => {
        console.log(`An unhandled error occurred in worker: ${err.filename}, line: ${err.lineno} :`);
        console.log(err.message);
    }

    worker.postMessage({url: "", filename: "up2"});
```

and my workername.js:

```
require('globals'); // necessary to bootstrap tns modules on the new thread

global.onmessage = function(msg) {
    var request = msg.data;
    var url = request.url;
    var filename = request.filename;

    var result = download(url, filename);

    var msg = result !== undefined ? { success: true, result: result } : { }

    global.postMessage(msg);
}


function download(url, name) {
    return ...
}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

I have used the same way explained [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/worker-loader)
and don't forget to configure your Webpack config file like this:

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin([
                { from: { glob: 'css/**', dot: false } },
               -> { from: { glob: 'shared/workers/**', dot: false } },
                { from: { glob: 'images/**', dot: false } },
                { from: { glob: 'fonts/**', dot: false } },
                { from: { glob: 'sounds/**', dot: false } },
                { from: { glob: '**/*.jpg', dot: false } },
                { from: { glob: '**/*.png', dot: false } },
            ], copyIgnore),
```