# NativeScript Web Worker, keeps giving error: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to find module: relative to app//

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, multithreading, nativescript

Using Nativescript & Angular I have been trying to implement a clock counter in a Web Worker thread.
Currently, the app initiates the clock counter using a `setInterval` function and although that works, it implies that the clock counter is on the main thread where it doesn't need to be.
So, the intention is to move the clock counter to a different thread and therefore not burden the main thread.

I started of simple, trying to write similar code that I got from this page: [frenetic.be](http://frenetic.be/tricks/simple-timer.php)

However, trying to initialize the worker process as `w = new Worker("simple-timer.js");`

But this lead me to the error:
`ERROR Error: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to find module: "simple-timer.js" relative to app//`
despite the fact that the file was in the same folder as the component from which it was called.

So, digging deeper, I ended up trying to make sense of the [nativescript page on web workers](https://docs.nativescript.org/advanced-concepts.html#multithreading-workers)
This seems to imply that it should be relatively simple and that the `new Worker()` should be called with a valid path argument. Though this failed, with the same error as above.

So taking the deep-dive, I tried to follow the following instructions: [github page](https://github.com/NativeScript/worker-loader)
Though this managed to f*ck up things even further.
Though there is one step that I couldn't do (step 2 in Usage Typescript) [github page, section](https://github.com/NativeScript/worker-loader#usage-in-typescript-projects)
Which refers to the `references.d.ts` but that file is apparently no longer part of the nativescript file set for an app.

So, I reduced to simpler means and downloaded the angular-demo file and looked if I could understand the method they followed. Copied the service, almost 1-1 and added a testmethod to my component.
That gave an `plugin` error, so, I added the plugin reference as per section 7 & 8 on the [github page](https://github.com/NativeScript/worker-loader)

Although this get's me quite far, I now still end up with the same error?

For some reason, the file paths simply do not seem to be translated correctly and hence the correct files are not found?

I have also looked at:
[How to use Nativescript worker with typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46784340/how-to-use-nativescript-worker-with-typescript)

and this one
[Is it feasible to use web worker (multi-threading) in Angular and Typescript in NativeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42488667/is-it-feasible-to-use-web-worker-multi-threading-in-angular-and-typescript-in)

Anybody have usefull tips on how to implement this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You have to include your worker(s) files to Webpack using config file so I have just added this line to webpack.config.js and it worked!

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin([
  { from: { glob: 'css/**', dot: false } },
->{ from: { glob: 'backgroundTasks/**', dot: false } },
  { from: { glob: 'images/**', dot: false } },
  { from: { glob: 'fonts/**', dot: false } },
  { from: { glob: 'sounds/**', dot: false } },
  { from: { glob: '**/*.jpg', dot: false } },
  { from: { glob: '**/*.png', dot: false } },
 ], copyIgnore),
```